# Does equal sizes of two sets imply they have the same cardinality in general?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

This may seem like a silly question (and it certainly seems that way asking it) but I want to make sure my thought process is correct.

If two sets *have the same cardinality* then we can define a function $f: A \to B$ that is one-to-one and onto. *Cardinality* refers to the size of the sets.

Suppose instead I have two sets I know are the same size. Fixing an example:

$A: \{1, 2, 3\}$

$B: \{4, 5, 6\}$

Each has 3 elements. Since they have the same size, does this imply I can find a one-to-one and onto function $f: A \to B$? I would guess so. If I had to pin point my confusion - I think it comes from *defining* the function. In this case, I think I can define a a function $f = a + 3$, that maps exactly one element of $a \in A$ to every $b \in B$, and every $b \in B$ has some $a \in A$ such that $f(a) = b$.

Is this true in general?

Comment: What does "size" even mean? Usually, the size of a finite set is $n$ iff you can find a bijective function from the first $n$ natural numbers to a given set. With that definition, your question becomes clear, as one can compose bijections to make another bijection. It should be noted that just because it's hard for you to find a bijection, or write it out, doesn't mean it isn't there.

Comment: @DonThousand That is a good question, I get size is only "defined" for finite sets. Are you implying that if a set has a defined cardinality it is also countable?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by defined cardinality

Comment: huh good question, I dont really know either. I guess in my head I was thinking of a set that is finite. The "size" is defined (not infinite).

Comment: Size is usually defined by a bijection, even for finite sets. You can see clearly how this answers your question?

Comment: Ah yes, the book I am using doesnt use the term _bijection_ but looking it up I see what you mean. If there is a bijection between the two sets, it must be the case they are the same size. Similarly, if they are the same size, we should always be able to find a bijection for them. Again I am using size loosely as the number of elements in a finite set. If I understand it with this, please post the answer so I can give you a green check.

Comment: That's correct. In fact, the observation that there exists a bijection and the sets have the same size is trivial, as size is defined in terms of bijections. So, if set A and B have the same "size", they both share a bijection to the same set, so one can compose the bijections.

Comment: I personally don't care too much for reputation, so I wouldn't worry about giving me the green check. Cheers! Hope that helped.

Comment: Very much so, thank you very much! @DonThousand

Comment: Your question is indeed asked in a weird way. It roughly amounts to "the cardinality is the size; do two sets of the same size have the same cardinality ?"

Comment: A function is a set of ordered pairs that obeys certain constraints. There’s no particular reason that it should have an associated formula. $f=\{(1,6),(2,4),(3,5)\}$ is another perfectly good bijection between the two sets, one for which you’ll have to jump through some hoops to find a closed formula. What if the elements of the two sets were the symbols $a$ through $f$ instead of numbers?

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. I suppose what I was getting at is that there is _some_ function for it. As DonThousand had mentioned - just because we can't find one via trial and error doesn't mean it doesn't exist. You've demonstrated that clearly by providing another bijection for this sample. @YvesDaoust - I know, I could've worded it better. I had a hard time finding any way to ask it without saying "are two sets that are the same size the same size?". Im glad I didn't confused people too bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Notation.** "$X\lesssim Y$" is notation for "there exists a 1-to-1 function from $X$ to $Y$."

**Notation.** "$X\sim Y$" is notation for "there exists a 1-to-1 onto function from $X$ to $Y$."

**Terminology.** Say $X$ is *finite* if there exists a natural number $n$ such that $X\lesssim\{1,\ldots,n\}$.

**Definition.** Let $X$ be a nonempty finite set. The *cardinality* of $X$, denoted $\#X$, is $$\min\{n\in\mathbb{N}:X\lesssim\{1,\ldots,n\}\}.$$

**Theorem.** Let $X$ be a nonempty finite set. Then $$\{n\in\mathbb{N}:X\sim \{1,\ldots,n\}\}=\{\#X\}.$$

**Corollary.** Let $X$ and $Y$ be nonempty sets of the same size. That is to say, $\#X=\#Y$. Then there exists a bijection from $X$ to $Y$. That is to say, $X\sim Y$.

*Proof.* Assume $\#X=\#Y$. Fix a bijection $\phi:X\to\{1,\ldots,\#X\}$. Fix a bijection $\psi:Y\to\{1,\ldots,\#Y\}$. Then $\psi^{-1}\circ\phi$ is a bijection from $X$ to $Y$ as desired. $\square$

Answer (score 0):

You can number the elements of a finite set, i.e. associate to every element a natural in $[1,n]$ where $n$ is the cardinality. This numbering is a bijection.

Then you can match any two sets of the same cardinality by relating the elements with the same index. This defines the bijection you are looking for.

Note that this also holds for infinite countable sets.

Comment: Note that this reasoning is close to circular, as $[1,n]$  is itself a set. We can rephrase the numbering process by stating that "it is possible to remove an element from a non-empty finite set" and combine with the principle of induction.

Answer (score 0):

Choose arbitrarily an element from $A$ and an element from $B$ and remove them, as long as the sets are non-empty.

If the sets are finite, the process will stop. If they have the same size, they will both be empty, and all their elements have been associated in pairs, defining a bijection.